# io_service::poll_one non-deterministic behaviour

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In the following code, I expect the output to always be 1, because I am expecting only one handler to run when `poll_one()` is called. However, once in about 300 times, the output is actually 3. Based on my understanding of the boost library, this seems incorrect. Is the non-deterministic behavior a bug or expected?

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::io_service::work io_work(io);
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand1(io);
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand2(io);
  int val = 0;

  strand1.post([&val, &strand2]() {
    val = 1;
    strand2.post([&val]() {
      val = 2;
    });
    boost::asio::spawn(strand2, [&val](boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
      val = 3;
    });
  });

  io.poll_one();
  std::cout << "Last executed: " << val << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Using boost-asio 1.60.0.6

Comment: Why downvote? Answer appreciated

Comment: Of course it is complete minimal and verifiable and easily compilable. Exceptions are not thrown.

Comment: If you reduce number of cases from 3 to 2 problem is not appearing

Comment: Any reason  why this has been downvoted?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ aside from 2 missing includes and the noise of the try/catch, I found the code to be close to a [mcve]. /cc Michal when providing a complete example, removing code paths that are never being executed, especially those with significant distractions, such as the try/catch, is extremely helpful to those trying to provide assistance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This post never was in any problems, but your comments make it look that way. Comments have real consequences. Please consider that leaving things - outside your absolute center of expertise, perhaps -  alone if you don't see an immediate lead to help someone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The observed behavior is well defined and expected to occur, but one should not expected it to occur often.

Asio has a limited pool of strand implementations, and the default allocation strategy for strands is hashing.  If a hash collision occurs, two strands will use the same implementation.  When a hash-collision occurs, the example simplifies to the following [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82c283c7a8388d52):

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand1(io_service);
  // Have strand2 use the same implementation as strand1.
  boost::asio::io_service::strand strand2(strand1);

  int value = 0;
  auto handler1 = [&value, &strand1, &strand2]() {
    assert(strand1.running_in_this_thread());
    assert(strand2.running_in_this_thread());
    value = 1;

    // handler2 is queued into strand and never invoked.
    auto handler2 = [&value]() { assert(false); };
    strand2.post(handler2);

    // handler3 is immediately executed.
    auto handler3 = [&value]() { value = 3; };
    strand2.dispatch(handler3);
    assert(value == 3);
  };

  // Enqueue handler1.
  strand1.post(handler1);

  // Run the event processing loop, executing handler1.
  assert(io_service.poll_one() == 1);
}
```

In the above example:

- `io_service.poll_one()` executes a single ready handler (`handler1`)
- `handler2` is never invoked
- `handler3` is invoked immediately within [`strand2.dispatch()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html), as `strand2.dispatch()` is invoked from within a handler where `strand2.running_in_this_thread()` returns `true`

---

There are various details contributing to the observed behavior:

- [`io_service::poll_one()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll_one/overload1.html) will run the `io_service`'s event loop and without blocking, it will execute at most one ready to run handler.  Handlers executed immediately within the context of a `dispatch()` are never enqueued into the `io_service`, and are not subject to `poll_one()`'s limit of invoking a single handler.
- The [`boost::asio::spawn(strand, function)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn/overload3.html) overload starts a stackful coroutine *as-if* by `strand.dispatch()`:

  - if `strand.running_in_this_thread()` returns `false` for the caller, then the coroutine will be posted into the `strand` for deferred invocation
  - if `strand.running_in_this_thread()` returns `true` for the caller, then the coroutine will be executed immediately
- Discrete `strand` objects that use the same implementation still maintain the guarantees of a strand.  Namely, concurrent execution will not occur and the [order of handler invocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__strand.order_of_handler_invocation) is well defined.  When discrete `strand` objects are using discrete implementations, and multiple threads are running the `io_service`, then one may observe the discrete strands executing concurrently.  However, when discrete `strand` objects use the same implementation, one will not observe concurrency even if multiple threads are running the `io_service`.  This behavior is [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__strand.remarks):

  > The implementation makes no guarantee that handlers posted or dispatched through different strand objects will be invoked concurrently.
- Asio has a limited pool of strand implementations.  The current default is `193` and can be controlled by defining `BOOST_ASIO_STRAND_IMPLEMENTATIONS` to the desired number.  This feature is noted in the [Boost.Asio 1.48 release notes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_6_1___boost_1_48)

  > Made the number of strand implementations configurable by defining `BOOST_ASIO_STRAND_IMPLEMENTATIONS` to the desired number.

  By decreasing the pool size, one increases the chance that two discrete strands will use the same implementation.  With the original code, if one was to set the pool size to `1`, then `strand1` and `strand2` will always use the same implementation, resulting in `val` always being `3` ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d98ac182372d4192)).
- The default strategy for allocating strand implementations is to use a golden-ratio hash.  As a hashing algorithm is used, there is a potential for collisions, resulting in the same implementation being used for multiple discrete `strand` objects.  By defining `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_SEQUENTIAL_STRAND_ALLOCATION`, one can change the allocation strategy to round-robin, preventing a collision from occurring until `BOOST_ASIO_STRAND_IMPLEMENTATIONS + 1` strand allocations have occurred.  This feature is noted in the Boost.Asio 1.48 release notes:

  > Added support for a new `BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_SEQUENTIAL_STRAND_ALLOCATION` flag which switches the allocation of strand implementations to use a round-robin approach rather than hashing.

Given the above details, the following occurs when `1` is observed in the original code:

- `strand1` and `strand2` have discrete implementations
- `io_service::poll_one()` executes the single handler that was posted directly into `strand1`
- the handler that was posted into `strand1` sets `val` to `1`
- the handler posted into `strand2` is enqueued and never invoked
- the coroutine creation is deferred, as `strand`'s order of invocation guarantee prevents the coroutine from being created until after the previous handler that was posted into `strand2` has executed:

  > given a strand object `s`, if `s.post(a)` happens-before `s.dispatch(b)`, where the latter is performed outside the strand, then `asio_handler_invoke(a1, &a1)` happens-before `asio_handler_invoke(b1, &b1)`.

On the other hand, when `3` is observed:

- a hash-collision occurs for `strand1` and `strand2`, resulting in them using the same underlying strand implementation
- `io_service::poll_one()` executes the single handler that was posted directly into `strand1`
- the handler that was posted into `strand1` sets `val` to `1`
- the handler posted into `strand2` is enqueued and never invoked
- the coroutine is immediately created and invoked within `boost::asio::spawn()`, setting `val` to `3`, as `strand2` can safely execute the coroutine while maintaining the guarantee of non-concurrent execution and order of handler invocation

Comment: This answer is a piece of art. I loved the small demos of the edge cases. +100 AFAIAC

Comment: Awesome answer. This would be valuable information to have in the documentation of the strand class.

Comment: @sehe Thank you!  Your dedication to providing outstanding answers across SO over the years has been a tremendous motivation for me.  This answer would not be here without you.