# asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> vs io_context::strand

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Since latest versions of boost, asio comes up with its new executors and provides with `asio::strand<Executor>`. So it is now perfectly possible to use `asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type>` instead of `io_context::strand`. But they cannot be used interchangeably.

- Could someone explain what is the difference in usage with examples?
- Their advantage/inconvenient compared to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`io_context::strand` is "legacy". I assumed it exists for interface compatibility with code that still uses `boost::asio::io_service` (also deprecated).

> As the comments reflect I've since found out that `io_context::strand` is not actually deprecated, although I see no reason why this is the case, and close reading of the implementation leaves me with the conclusion that
>
> - `asio::strand<Executor>` is strictly better
> - mixing both strand services is not the best idea. In fact both services are documented with the same tag line:
>
>   ```
>    // Default service implementation for a strand.
>   ```
>
>   I can't help feeling there should be only one default :)

Modern strands don't reference an execution context, but wrap an executor.

While being technically different, it is conceptually the same.

The usage is the same for posting tasks:

```
post(s, task); // where s is either legacy or modern 
defer(s, task);
dispatch(s, task);
```

> In fact you may have tasks with an *associated executor*, see:
>
> - [When must you pass io_context to boost::asio::spawn? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66731990/when-must-you-pass-io-context-to-boostasiospawn-c/66733239#66733239)
> - [Which io_context does std::boost::asio::post / dispatch use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458609/which-io-context-does-stdboostasiopost-dispatch-use/52460852#52460852)

You can no longer use the legacy strand to *construct IO service objects* (like tcp::socket or steady_timer). That's because the legacy strand cannot be type-erased into `any_io_executor`:

```
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
boost::asio::io_context ioc;

auto modern = make_strand(ioc.get_executor());
tcp::socket sock(modern);

boost::asio::io_context::strand legacy(ioc);
tcp::socket sock(legacy); // COMPILE ERROR
```

If you really want you can force it by not using `any_io_executor`:

```
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<tcp, decltype(legacy)> sock(legacy);
sock.connect({{}, 8989});
```

Comment: Fixed a few accuracy issues and added relevant examples.

Comment: Hi @sehe, thank you for your clear answer. Just cross checked again the very latest ASIO documentation (both boost 1.75 and standalone 1.18.1), I don't see io_context::strand as deprecated. Anyway, good to know that I'd better go for strand<executor_type> version.

Comment: Oh my. I keep thinking I know Asio. And then I'm proving myself wrong. I'm surprised that inner type `strand` isn't deprecated like innert type `work` (`make_strand` and `strand<executor_type>` seemed similar to `make_work_guard` and `executor_work_guard<executor_type>` so I connected them in my mind). Surprisingly the legacy strand (I'll keep referring to it as that) has it's own _separate_ IO service implementation backing it (`strand_service`), which 99% duplicates the newer `strand_executor_service`. The latter is strictly more generic and flexible (w.r.t composed/modified executors e.g.)

Comment: The only functional difference I see is that one can no longer force a different number of strand "buckets" (~the number of unique mutex instances) (using `BOOST_ASIO_STRAND_IMPLEMENTATIONS` as [explained in this easily underrated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38669846/85371) by @TannerSansbury. And note that effectively, when using both strand services, you're effectively  doubling the number of strand implementations. I find it surprising that these both exist without one being deprecated.

Comment: (Fixed my mistaken claims in the answer text)

Comment: Well, when I read all your contributions in SO, for sure you know asio better than me, and your support is much valuable and appreciated!!